# AngularJS ui-router wait for parent state to resolve before child state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a parent route to finish resolving before I resolve my child states data. Currently, the child state is resolving independently.

In the code below, I want to not resolve the organization in the child state (and this initialize my controller) until the rpe is resolved in the parent state.

Been looking at this for the last couple of hrs, but can't seem to figure it out. Would appreciate any help!

Package info:

```
ui-router: 1.0.0-beta.1
angular: 1.5.9
```

Here is the code:

```
.state('app', {
  url: '/app',
  abstract: true,
  template: '<app layout="row" flex></app>',
  resolve: {
    // other resolves
    rpe: ['authUser', 'RPEService',
      function (authUser, RPEService) {
        return RPEService.init();
      }
    ]
  }
})
.state('app.dashboard', {
  url: '/dashboard/?supportchat',
  template: '<dashboard flex organization="$resolve.organization"></dashboard>',
  data: {
    title: 'Dashboard',
    hideBack: true
  },
  resolve: {
    organization: ['OrganizationService', 'AuthService', function (OrganizationService, AuthService) {
      return OrganizationService.find(AuthService.user.organization_id).then(response => {
        return response.data;
      });
    }]
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example on any sandbox online?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried injecting the parent resolve as a dependency to the child state? Something like this:

```
.state('app', {
  url: '/app',
  abstract: true,
  template: '<app layout="row" flex></app>',
  resolve: {
    // other resolves
    rpe: ['authUser', 'RPEService',
      function (authUser, RPEService) {
        return RPEService.init();
      }
    ]
  }
})
.state('app.dashboard', {
  url: '/dashboard/?supportchat',
  template: '<dashboard flex organization="$resolve.organization"></dashboard>',
  data: {
    title: 'Dashboard',
    hideBack: true
  },
  resolve: {
    organization: ['OrganizationService', 'AuthService', 'rpe', function (OrganizationService, AuthService, rpe) {
      return OrganizationService.find(AuthService.user.organization_id).then(response => {
        return response.data;
      });
    }]
  }
})
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that. Didn't help. If that's supposed to work it could be an issue with the version of ui-router I'm on? I'm on 1.0.0-beta.1